# How to align terms in equations?

Tags: equations, align

This:

```
\begin{align*}
      & N 2^{H(p)} c(\hash)          & + 2^{H(p)} c(\enc) &\\
    = & 2^{H(p) + \log_2 N} c(\hash) & + 2^{H(p)} c(\enc) &\\
\end{align*}
```

is ugly:

[image]

because the plus sign, alongside the 2nd term, is too squeezed to the right side.

**Question:** how to properly align this?  My goal is to make it noticeable that the 2nd term is identical.

Comment: How do you want it aligned?  Generally, the terms will alternate aligned right and then left.  If you want everything aligned right, remove the `&`.  But it's not clear how you want it to look.

Comment: @Teepeemm - I want the bottom line (= ...) to appear totally normally as if it was a single equation like usual.  I want the top line to have its + sign space so that falls right over the + sign below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the = to the left of `&` use `={}&` to get the relation spacing. Also use `\mathrm` (or `\mathit`) for multi-letter identifiers. Use `alignat` rather than `align` to avoid adding space between the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\hash{\mathrm{hash}}
\newcommand\enc{\mathrm{enc}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
      & N 2^{H(p)} c(\hash)          && + 2^{H(p)} c(\enc) \\
    ={} & 2^{H(p) + \log_2 N} c(\hash) && + 2^{H(p)} c(\enc) \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  Side question:  is `\mathrm{hash}` in math mode going to render like `hash` in normal text mode?  Or is there a difference that I am not seeing?  My concern is:  if I do `blah $\enc$ blah`, then it may appear as just `blah enc blah`, without any visible cue that `\enc` is not a normal text.

Comment: @caveman if you want it italic use `\mathit{enc}` not `\mathrm{enc}` just don't use `enc` the default math font is explicitly designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but like a product of single letter variables. Compare `$diff$` and `$\mathit{diff}$`

Comment: How about `\mathtt{...}`?  Will my document still look like those made by cool kids?  Or is `\mathtt{...}` frowned upon for such scenarios?  My visual taste prefers the latter one, but I am not sure if I am right.

Comment: I don't have the mathematical context of the rest of the document, \mathtt isn't used much in pure mathematical expressions mostly in computer science disciplines closer to pseudocode, but it's your document and your subject area. @caveman

Comment: Possible definitions for `\enc` include: `\textnormal{\sffamily\slshape enc}`, `\textsl{enc}` (if you have different slanted and italic font faces), `\textsc{enc}` and `\mathsfit{enc}` (with `unicode-math` or `isomath`). Try them and see!